# Dependency conflict resolution in Play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, ivy, playframework-2.2

I'm using play framework to develop my application.

My application is dependent on a library which in turn is dependent on "org.apache.httpcomponents" "httpclient" "4.3.1" i.e. 4.3.1 version of apache httpclient. But I have added the below dependency in my build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.2"
```

I want SBT to resolve the conflict by adding 4.2 version of the httpclient in the classpath.

When I run "play classpath" I get the 4.3.1 version of httpclient as a dependency. How do I enforce SBT to pick "4.2" version of httpclient in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you add `force()` to the end:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.2" force()
```

Source: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Management.html#Forcing+a+revision

Comment: force() is [no longer recommended](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Management.html#Forcing+a+revision+%28Not+recommended%29).

Answer (score 1):

Force can work, but really you want to see who is pulling in the old version and add an exclude. See http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Management.html#Exclude+Transitive+Dependencies